# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: count

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel

I write a site with asp.net core 2.0, sometimes following error raise(rarely).

> An unhandled exception has occurred: Specified argument was out of
>   the range of valid values. Parameter name: count

StackTrace:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name: count at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowFailed()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetResult(ReadResult&
>   result) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.IReadableBufferAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.System.IO.Pipelines.ReadableBufferAwaitable.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.d__24.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<ProcessRequestsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext()

**I`m not sure, but this error probably after I migrate to asp.net core 2.0.**

Comment: Does this error happens in a specific controller,method or operation?

Comment: @Afshar. sometimes occur in some action not always.

Comment: I'm seeing this error come through too and I can't replicate it. Looks like you've created an issue for it: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/2128

Comment: @Gary Brunton, yes I do

Comment: Same here... this weird error pops up infrequently on our dotnet core 2.0 api. Have no idea why it does.